# Fermat's Figurate Number Theory

Tags: discrete-mathematics, fermat-numbers

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{i(i+1)...(i+k-1)}{k!}=\frac{n(n+1)...(n+k)}{(k+1)!}$$
Regard ***"k"*** as a fixed positive integer,

How can I prove this formula of Fermat by using induction on ***"n"***. I am not a mathematician. I am trying to understand the Fermat's approach to Quadratures, out of date form of Calculus.I have tried but not achieved.

Comment: Please don't use pictures.
See [here](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text), why.
Use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: I 've revised it. Thank you for the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two parts to a typical proof by mathematical induction.

1. the base case (here we may take $n=0$).  That's easy in this case, both sides are $0$..
2. the induction step.  Suppose it's true for $n$, and check that this implies it's true for $n+1$.  Comparing the sum for $n$ and the sum for $n+1$, there is one additional term, the one for $i=n+1$.  So here you want to check that
   $$ \frac{n(n+1)\ldots (n+k)}{(k+1)!} + \frac{(n+1)(n+2)\ldots(n+k)}{k!} =
   \frac{(n+1)(n+2)\ldots (n+k+1)}{(k+1)!} $$

Comment: Thank you for your help. By the way, I have noticed that I didn't mention about regarding "k" as a positive integer and should be proved by induction on "n".